# RestTemplate with Google App Engine

Tags: spring, sockets, google-app-engine, spring-data-neo4j, resttemplate

I have a Google AppEngine Application with Spring Framework that has to make a post request with a List  to another Spring Boot Application that exposes REST API.
 I am using RestTemplate for calling the api.

Inside the GAE Application I do:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(NEO4J_URL_VERTEX, vertices, List.class);
```

The Spring Boot application connects to a local Neo4j database. At `NEO4J_URL_VERTEX` I have the following method that saves the vertices to the db:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "vertex/all", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void addVertex(@RequestBody List<Vertex> vertices) {
        for (Vertex v : vertices) {
            Vertex old = vertexService.findByEmail(v.getEmail());
            if (old == null) {
                vertexService.create(v);
             }
        }
}
```

The scenario works well for small lists with small Vertex objects. But most often I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/vertex/all":Socket operation timed out: The API call remote_socket.Receive() took too long to respond and was cancelled.; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Socket operation timed out: The API call remote_socket.Receive() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:330)
```

**Important to note here is that the vertices are saved to the Neo4j database.** There is no problem with that. GAE Application makes the post request with the list of objects, but after some time(aprox 1 sec) closes the socket because apparently that is too long. But the Spring Application with the Neo4j continues to write the vertices and they are eventually all saved to the database.

I have tried already to iterate the List in the GAE Application and make a POST for each Vertex, but again if the Vertex object is large (i.e. has many teammates) I get the same error. 
The Vertex object is defined as:

```
public class Vertex  {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Index(unique=true)
    private String email;
    @Index(unique=true)
    private Long universeUserId;

    @Relationship(type="WORKS_WITH", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private  List<Edge> teammates;

//getters,setters
}
```

After reading a bit I have tried to configure the socket timeout by doing:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setReadTimeout(50000);
        factory.setConnectTimeout(50000);
        return factory;
    }
```

But that did not help. Moreover, the method from the GAE application which posts the vertices is called from Appengine's

> Task Queue

which has a 10min time limitation so that is not the problem. For the moment both applications run on localhost. 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: how many objects are you creating? i suspect this is not a spring data problem.

Comment: @MihaiRaulea 61 vertex objects. It is not a spring data problem, that's right. I believe it is a Google App Engine problem. If I am calling my Spring Boot application's post method with a list of vertices from Postman or any Rest client I have no problem with saving the data in Neo4j db. Actually, even if I call it from my GAE Application the vertices are saved. But in GAE I get that error, that socket connection was cancelled.

Comment: Google App Engine and listening to sockets...